# is it possible to output different values of different values from a class array into a file

Tags: c++, arrays, class, file-io

We are doing an assignment with classes and objects and all that messy stuff.

I'm having a problem in which, when the user is done editing the array (adding or deleting data, blah blah blah), I need to update the `.dat` file with the values in the array for later use. I'm having a bit of trouble outputting the values into the file.

Any tips?

if this question has already been answered, just link me to the source and I'll delete this question.

ALSO, PLEASE NOTE THAT THE LIST ARRAY VARIABLE IN THE CODE IS FROM A CLASS.

Here is the test data (values are `string`, `int`, `int`, `int`, `int`, in that order):

```
MAN 5 9 2 89
LOL 4 3 8 23
SAP 7 2 2 34
```

And here is my code:

```
string name;
int gamesPlayed, goalsFor, goalsAgainst, points;

while (outfile << name << gamesPlayed << goalsFor << goalsAgainst << points)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numofclubs; i++)
    { 
        outfile = list[i];
    }
}

outfile.close();
```

Comment: Unrelated, *"with classes and object and all that messy stuff"* does not ring confidence in the code, or the quality thereof, which you're authoring. Regardless, if `outfile` in the fragment you chose to bless us with is an output stream, there is little wonder what you have doesn't work; frankly it shouldn't even *compile*. I'd bet lunch you meant for `outfile = list[i];` to be `outfile << list[i];` . Even then, since you're providing no whitespace separation in your writes, the final result stands no chance of being what you desire.

Comment: where is the data stored? I mean in the app , dont say "I have to store it in a file".

Comment: @WhozCraig thats because im not confident in the code haha. and ok i see but i did outfile << list[i] and an error came up saying "theres no operator matches these operands". I'll clean up the output of the code later i just want it to function.

Comment: @pm100 haha alright i wont. Its stored in a constructor class object (At least thats what i think thats what its called

Comment: @errorManufacturer please STOP SHOUTING at people. And if you want people to be able to help you, please [edit] your question to provide a minimal reproducible example showing what your data array looks like and how it is organized before you try to write its values to the file.

Answer (score 2):

You are not writing any delimiters between your values in the file.  And, inside your `for` loop, you are trying to assign a value to the `ofstream` itself, rather than write the value to the file managed by the `ofstream`.

Also, you say the data is in an array, but you didn't show what that array actually looks like. Your `while` loop is not looping through any array.  And your `for` loop is writing out club information that is not consistent with the desired file format you have described.

You probably need something more like this instead:

```
class Club
{
    string name;
    int gamesPlayed, goalsFor, goalsAgainst, points;
};

Club* list;
int numofclubs;

...

ofstream outfile("output.dat");

for (int i = 0; i < numofclubs; ++i)
{ 
    outfile << list[i].name << ' '
            << list[i].gamesPlayed << ' '
            << list[i].goalsFor << ' '
            << list[i].goalsAgainst << ' '
            << list[i].points << '\n';
}

outfile.close();
```

Comment: oh ok i see it seems i was way off the mark than i thought it was. Kinda embarrassing. Ill adapt my code now and update you if it works

Comment: i had to adapt ur answer a bit (instead of calling members which caused an error i called the actual functions in the class e.g GetName() and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help u saved my ass

Comment: @errorManufacturer well, considering that you didn't show what the array looked like, I couldn't have possibly given you that answer up front.  Next time you post a question, don't leave out *relevant* details like that.